# What is the purpose of create temporary databases in python sqlite3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executescript("""
create table person(
firstname,
lastname,
age
);
create table book(

title,
author,
published
);
insert into book(title, author, published)
values (
'Dirk Gently''s Holistic Detective Agency',
'Douglas Adams',
1987
);
""")
cur.execute("""
SELECT * FROM book
""")

print(conn)
conn.commit()
x=cur.fetchall()
print(x)
```

I refer the book and It given code like this. In here you can see the database name mention as "**:memory:**" so what does it means?. I supposed it's use to create temporary database in RAM but when I execute this code, It's running but when **I *fetchall()*** and print it, It shows **empty list**. What is the reason for that what is the **usage of the temporary databases**.And otherthing is I'm not using normal ***execute*** method in here. I am using ***exeutesscript*** method in here. Can you help me?

Comment: something else means

Comment: In here I using executingscript method, not the execute method.

Comment: You insert a record into the Book table, but then you select from the Person table, which is indeed empty as you didn't insert any record to it.

Comment: yeah, I corret it. But I want to clarify here about temporary databases.

Answer (score 2):

The point of `:memory` database is operate a database without persisting data to disk.  For instance, you could use sqlite3 to manage in-memory application state while having all the features of the database available.  In-process caching would be a special case of that.  You may only care about the data for a short time, say, during a test run (q&a), or to eliminate i/o service times as variable for benchmarks.

`executescript()` ignores the result of a select per https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c which says:

> /* execute statement, and ignore results of SELECT statements */

After `executescript()`, use `execute()` for the `select` statement.  I dropped the unused `create person` and  reformatted the remaining two statements for readability but the original queries are otherwise unchanged:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executescript("""
create table book(title, author, published);
insert into book(title, author, published) values (
  'Dirk Gently''s Holistic Detective Agency', 'Douglas Adams', 1987
);
""")

cur.execute("select * from book;")
print(cur.fetchall())
```

which returns:

```
[("Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency", 'Douglas Adams', 1987)]
```

Comment: I try this in your way but not print anything. Plz determine I am using a temporary database(:memory:) and also I am using executing script here. And why someone down vote in here until no one can't be written a real answer? Is it automatically happen?

Comment: I updated my answer with self-contained code instead of only the required diff, along with the data received when I run it.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. what is the usage of a temporary database?

Comment: Just updated my answer with that info :-)